# how to add new conversion at google-analytics 4? (just simple /thanks page checking)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to create conversion for my new ga4 account, just simple checking of /thanks page .

[image: new conversion adding]

it shows in a list when I click @Save button, look here

[image]

but then I refresh this page (F5), it removes

[image]

How to add just simple checking of visiting /thanks page at my site at new GA4 ???
how to define /thanks checking as goals?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an event in GA4, there aren't pageviews. So just send an event when page path equals `/thanks` and mark it as convertion.